# How to load image into memory and then save to Firebase Storage in Flutter / Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I load a photo from an URL into memory (using the 'get' method from the http package) and then try to save it as a file in Firebase Storage.

This is the code I am using:

```
response = await http.get(photoUrl);
file = File.fromRawPath(response.bodyBytes);
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path).putFile(file);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error: 'package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 62 pos 12: 'file.existsSync()': is not true.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you read the **content** of the photo into memory, it is **not** a file and `` makes no sense.

To upload the raw data from memory, you should use the [`StorageReference.putData` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageReference/putData.html).

Something like:

```
response = await http.get(photoUrl);
var bytes = response.bodyBytes;
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path).putData(bytes);
```